# Make operating system with Ubuntu?

Tags: system, programming

I just had a quick question is it true that you can make your own operating system with Ubuntu and if so where can i go to learn how to make my own operating system with Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: You can start by reading articles [like this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-operating-system-linux-scratch-linux-si/). Also check [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) out.

Answer (score 0):

You can have another operating system alongside with Ubuntu or another operating system inside Ubuntu.
If you want to have another operating system with Ubuntu, for example windows, you have to install windows first and then Ubuntu. This is easy way instead of installing Ubuntu first and then Windows.
But if you want to install another operating system, for example Windows in Ubuntu, You have to use of a virtual program like Vitualbox, which is very useful and easy to use. and you can get it through software center, or type the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

and then type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Done!

Comment: What's the use in checking for newly available packages AFTER installing software, without upgrading it too? I think it would be better to check for a newer software BEFORE installing a package. Also, xibit55 asked how to make his own OS, not how to run two (or more) side-by-side/with a Virtual Machine, if I read it correctly.

Comment: yeah, good. You are right. I thought, xibit55 is asking about dual boot OS.